# window.fnName and function are equal

Tags: javascript

I saw the javascript code

```
window.myfn=function(){}
```

My doubt is

```
function myfn(){
//some code.
}
```

and the window.myfn are same???

thanks in advance!!

Comment: The first one seems to be a global function to me.

Comment: Well the second is global as well, it will be assigned to the global namespace, if it's not within the scope of something else.

Comment: anybody explain with example!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the global scope,

```
function fn() { ... }
```

binds the name "fn" as a property of the global object to a function object. Thus, it's *almost* the same as

```
window.fn = function() { ... }
```

The difference is subtle and not terribly important in most cases, and has to do with the way that the "fn" symbol is available  in the scope inside the function.

Now, note that `window.name = value;` binds a value to a property of the global object anywhere it occurs (assuming of course that `window` hasn't been corrupted).  A function declaration statement may occur in any scope, and the binding will be relative to that context.